# WPF ComboBox prevent event on select item by code

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

**I have rephrased my question in EDIT 2**

All, I have a combobox in WPF. When I set SelectedIndex property, it fires a SelectionChanged event, which is the correct behavior. But what I want is to make ComboBox not fire an event when I set the SelectedIndex property programatically. Is there a way to do it?

I am using .Net 4.5

EDIT 1: Code

```
public void AddLocation()
{
    List<String> locations = new List<String>();

    //LocationBox is the name of ComboBox
    LocationBox.ItemsSource = locations;

    locations.Add("L1");
    locations.Add("B1");
    locations.Add("B3");
    LocationBox.SelectedIndex = 2; //<-- do not want to raise SelectionChanged event programmatically here
    locations.Add("G1");
    locations.Add("G2");
    locations.Add("F1");
    locations.Add("F3");
}

private void LocationBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(LocationBox.SelectedIndex);
}
```

EDIT 2: Rephrasing the question

I want to select an item in ComboBox silently i.e., without user interaction (using code/programmatically) so it doesn't fire a SelectionChanged event. How can I do that?

Comment: when you select particular index, you want that combobox is not working?

Comment: When I select a particular index programmatically, ComboBox fires SelectionChanged event. I do not want this in a particular case in my code. On the other hand it should fire SelectionChanged event when user interacts with the ComboBox

Comment: fire? i don't understand.. if you explain Words easy to understand,  I can help you :) and you should upload your source code

Comment: Fire is a synonym for Raise. To fire an event means to raise an event. I have added source code for your convenience.

Comment: Just curious, if you want NOT to raise it, why did you add the handler in the first place? What is your specific scenario why you add it but do not want to use it?

Comment: I have 20 RFID tags and 6 combo boxes on screen. User can select a tag from the combo box and see the updates on the screen. These tags are added when they are in the range of the antenna and removed when they are not in the range. While adding and re-adding I lose the current selection, but what I want to do is to keep the previous index selected if RFID is present in the newly scanned data which is done every 30 sec. cont....

Comment: I do not want to cause the SelectedChanged event to fetch the history of the tag from the database every 30 sec. This should be done only when RFID is removed from the list (then index 0 should be selected) or if the user selects a different RFID tag from the combo box. So I was looking for a simple way, this is possible in Apache Flex. When you change selection programmatically it fires a different event. So I was thinking if it was possible in WPF as well.

Comment: well .... you cannot "stop" event to trigger when that specific event happened. The choice you can have is having a flag e.g. IsIgnore = true;  => Locationbox.SeletedIndex = 2;  => IsIgnore = false;  .... and then simply return for nothing if IsIgnore == true in SlectionChanged event handler,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caveat for this Answer:

- This is hackish.
- This is bad.

I am giving you the benefit of doubt that maybe you are in the dilemma of modifying an existing code (or maybe some other reasons). Given the sample code, you can accomplish what you are trying to achieve by this code:

```
// Remove the handler
LocationBox.SelectionChanged -= LocationBox_SelectionChanged;
// Make a selection...
LocationBox.SelectedIndex = 2; //<-- do not want to raise SelectionChanged event programmatically here
// Add the handler again.
LocationBox.SelectionChanged += LocationBox_SelectionChanged;
```

Comment: Just answered your question above.

Comment: I actually have the same thing in mind, to remove and add the handler, and I was a bit reluctant on using this approach.

Comment: If you have the handler, it is impossible NOT to have if raised when you do a selection. That is how it is designed I think. Based on your reply on my question above, I think you can achieve it at the VM level not on the View level. But I think it requires another question.

Comment: Due to time limitation, I will go with this approach.

Comment: Well, comparing to your result. I rather do that by IsInitializing flag to wrap around SelectedIndex setting. Same hack but less impact I guess

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're trying not to fire the event when you are initializing the combo. You can use DataBinding to do that. There is an example below, but you can search for MVVM pattern for more details.

XAML:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding CBItems}"
          SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedCBItem}" />
```

CS:

```
public class ModelExample : INotfyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private int selectedCBItem;
    public int SelectedCBItem
    {
        get { return selectedCBItem; }
        set
        {
            selectedCBItem = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedCBItem));
        }
    }

    private List<ComboBoxItem> cbItems;
    public List<ComboBoxItem> CBItems
    {
        get { return cbItems; }
        set
        {
            cbItems= value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(CBItems));
        }
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public class ExampleWindow
{
    ...

    private ModelExample Model;

    private void Initialize()
    {
        ...
        this.DataContext = Model = new ModelExample();

        List<ComboBoxItem> items = // initialize your items somehow
        items.Add(new ComboBoxItem() { Content = "dummy item 1" });
        items.Add(new ComboBoxItem() { Content = "dummy item 2" });

        Model.CBItems = items;
        Model.SelectedCBItem = 1;
    }
}
```